# PayPal Plan execution fails getting description

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've setup the billing plan agreements using the API and everything is working fine on the sandbox. I've just tried my first live transaction but it fails trying to execute:

```
$agreement = new Agreement();
$agreement->execute($token, $apiContext);
```

Fails with:

"name":"CANNOT_FIND_PROFILE_DESC","message":"Profile description is invalid"

I have defined the description when creating the plan....

```
$plan = new Plan();
$plan->setName('Billing Plan')
->setDescription('Billing Plan')
->setType('fixed');
```

Comment: I found that the message is related to the agreement_description. I changed it to something short and it works. It was 92 characters long and contained a "@" character. It can be up to 127 so should have worked, as it does on the sandbox. Looks like I'll have do testing with live transactions.